# Is $A_n$ non-abelian for $n= 3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

In the book, it is asked to show that $A_n$ is non-abelian for $n ≥ 4$. Which may imply that it is abelian for $n=3$. Is that so? because $(13)(12)\ne (12)(13)$. Hence is it true to write: $A_n$ is non-abelian for $n ≥ 3$?

Can someone please guide me how to prove that $A_n$ is non-abelian, also?

Thank you.

Comment: $(13)$ and $(12)$ are not elements of $A_3$, which is in fact cyclic of order $3$.

Comment: $A_3$ has order $3!/2=3$. There is only one group of this order.

Answer (score 3):

$$A_3=\langle(123)\rangle$$ Hence it is cyclic.

Comment: Some times [this artical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) may helps you. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The group $A_3$ has order $3$, so it's abelian (even cyclic).

For $n>3$, you have $(123)$ and $(124)$ in $A_n$; try making their products in either order.

---

Note that $(12)\notin A_n$ for every $n$, because it's a transposition, so an odd permutation, so your argument doesn't work.